# How can I prove that $L_{[a]}$ is not injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

The function is $L_{[a]}([b]) = [a][b] = [ab]$, where $[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $[a]$ is not a unit.

I know that it is not surjective, since $[a]$ is not a unit so no element will give $[1]$, but I am lost for injectivity.

Basically I think I have to show that zero divisors are not unique, but I do not know how to show this for the general case $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: I think if you have $gcd(a,n)=1,$ then you can prove injectivity.

Comment: The domain and range of $L_{[a]}$ are same and finite, so if it is not surjective it cannot be injective.